# jqueryUI slider separate handle and filled bar

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Is there an easy way of having a separate value for the bar under the handle and the handle itself. 
So in this colorpicker demo 
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker
have the red bar of the first slider not have the same value as the handle on that slider?

This may sound counter-intuitive but it would come in handy. My current case is this:

I have a slider that controls a motor. I want the user to request a position with the handle and the red bar to show the actual position of the motor while it's moving. So the user requests a position and the red bar lags behind as the motor is moving towards the handle.

would this be possible with ui-slider-range?
Hope that makes sense since it is difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Just seeing this now from a search result.  It is possible. you'll need to copy and alter the j-query UI script.  There's a section towards the end of the slider script to set the range (do a find for   var oRange = this.options.range). It normally grabs the handle values, but you could add or subtract from that as needed.